# Cannot boot Linux from CD-ROM - "Media test failure, check cable" booting error

Tags: linux, boot, installation, bios, compact-disc

First time installing Linux. I have attempted to boot both Minimal Installation and LiveCD .iso Linux installation packages from a CD-ROM on a computer currently running Windows 7. This error does not occur with my Windows 7 installation disk. The following message is printed onto the screen twice before the computer reverts to the HDD:

```
Broadcom UNDI PXE 2.1 v11.0.11
Copyright (C) 2000-2008 Broadcom Corporation
Copyright (C) 1997-2000 Intel Corporation
All rights reserved.
PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable
PXE-M0F: Exiting Broadcom PXE ROM.
```

The [Intel website](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005740/boards-and-kits/desktop-boards.html) diagnoses the error as a hard drive or network cable issue, of which the former is working properly and the latter is unnecessary for an offline boot. Does a partition need to be created for the kernel and/or system files and packages, or is the computer missing drivers (and if so, how to boot them with Linux if necessary).

Comment: How did you create your bootable CD? Is booting from USB an option? It looks like the machine is trying to boot via network interface.

Comment: PXE is a network boot protocol and PXE boot would be handled by your motherboard firmware. The cable it wants you to check is the network cable, not the CDROM. The machine is not doing anything at all with your livecd and apparently doesn't think it is bootable.

Comment: I will be checking to see if I can turn off PXE in the BIOS menu and seeing if that will do the trick.

Comment: Update: I did not find a PXE switch, but I did find that the boot priority menu had empty USB HDD and USB ODD drives. Will investigate further.

Comment: If your CD is not bootable, as in it was not made correctly, then disabling PXE boot will do nothing. You are only seeing that message because it is *trying* to see if the CD is bootable and essentially dropping to a console while it does it. The Windows 7 CD will have the same thing going on, but the boot of the Windows  disk will be hiding the console. PXE is irrelevant here. As Patrick says, you need to check how you created the CD.

Comment: For `Windows 7`, you have [Windows Virtual PC](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=3702) available. You can make use of that.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which boot image you are using (and you computer boot firmware), you may be able to put it on to a USB storage device, and boot from that. Debian images a hybrid (they can be put on USB or DVD).

Another option, if you have a modern-ish CPU, is to install it into virtual box. This is my recommendation for a beginner. Install Virtual box into MS-Windows, then attach the DVD image to virtual box, and boot. You then install it into virtual box. There is then no worries about partitioning. It may run a little slower if you run games or 3d cad in the virtual machine, but other than that it will be near enough as fast as running on hardware. You can also run both OSs at the same time.